# Optimize highly vectorized code in Julia?

Tags: optimization, julia

I want to optimize the following code in Julia, it is written in a highly vectorized form at which languages like MATLAB excel. The exact same code in MATLAB takes `Elapsed time is 0.277608 seconds.`, that's 2.8X faster, so I thought something could be done in Julia. To be fair, I noticed that MATLAB uses multithreading by default, so no problem if multithreading is enabled in Julia too. Thank you for your help.

```
function fit_xlin(x, y, w)
    n = length(x)
    regularization = 1.0e-5
    xx_0_0 = fill(sum(w.*1)   , n)
    xx_1_0 = fill(sum(w.*x)   , n)
    xx_0_1 = fill(sum(w.*x)   , n)
    xx_1_1 = fill(sum(w.*x.*x), n)
    xy_0   = fill(sum(w.*y)   , n)
    xy_1   = fill(sum(w.*x.*y), n)
    xx_1_0 .+= regularization
    xx_0_1 .+= regularization

    xxk_0_0 = xx_0_0 .- w.*1
    xxk_1_0 = xx_1_0 .- w.*x
    xxk_0_1 = xx_0_1 .- w.*x
    xxk_1_1 = xx_1_1 .- w.*x.*x
    xyk_0   = xy_0   .- w.*y
    xyk_1   = xy_1   .- w.*x.*y

    det = xxk_0_0.*xxk_1_1 .- xxk_0_1.*xxk_1_0
    c0  = (xxk_1_1.*xyk_0  .- xxk_0_1.*xyk_1)./det
    c1  = (-xxk_1_0.*xyk_0 .+ xxk_0_0.*xyk_1)./det

    y_est = c0 .+ c1.*x
end 

using BenchmarkTools
function test_xlin()
    x = rand( 0.0:4.0, 5000_000)
    y = rand( 0.0:4.0, 5000_000)
    w = rand( 0.0:4.0, 5000_000)
    @btime fit_xlin($x, $y, $w)
end
```

This times as:

```
    julia> test_xlin();
      775.292 ms (46 allocations: 877.38 MiB)
```

Comment: There are probably many things to fix here, but the first thing to do is to change `sum(w.*1)` (that's terrible!) to `sum(w)`, `sum(w.*x)` to `dot(w, x)` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code that is still vectorized, and it does not use multithreading. On my computer it's a bit more than twice as fast as the original, but there is still things that can be done here.

BTW, I seriously doubt that the Matlab code is particularly optimized, since there are some very wasteful operations going on -- unnecessary allocation, unnecessary operations (`sum(w.*1)` is really bad, multiplying an array with 1 and allocating an extra array in the process is horribly wasteful :) Furthermore, you do not need to allocate any of the vectors `xx_0_0`, `xx_1_0` in Matlab either, you can just use broadcasting like in Julia.

Anyway, here's my first attempt:

```
function fit_xlin2(x, y, w)
    regularization = 1.0e-5

    sumwx = (w' * x) + regularization
    sumwy = (w' * y)
    sumwxx = sum(a[1]*a[2]^2 for a in zip(w, x))
    sumwxy = sum(prod, zip(w, x, y))

    wx = w .* x
    xxk_0_0 = sum(w) .- w
    xxk_1_0 = sumwx .- wx
    xxk_1_1 = sumwxx .- wx .* x
    xyk_0 = sumwy .- w .* y
    xyk_1 = sumwxy .- wx .* y

    det = xxk_0_0 .* xxk_1_1 .- xxk_1_0 .* xxk_1_0
    c0  = (xxk_1_1 .* xyk_0  .- xxk_1_0 .* xyk_1)./det
    c1  = (-xxk_1_0 .* xyk_0 .+ xxk_0_0 .* xyk_1)./det

    return c0 .+ c1 .* x
end
```

**Edit:** You can get a fair bit of speed-up by devectorizing the main loop. This code is ~17 times faster than the original Julia code, still single-threaded, and quite readable:

```
function fit_xlin_loop(x, y, w)
    if !(size(x) == size(y) == size(w))
        error("Input vectors must have the same size.")
    end

    regularization = 1.0e-5

    sumw = sum(w)
    sumwx = (w' * x) + regularization
    sumwy = (w' * y)
    sumwxx = sum(a[1]*a[2]^2 for a in zip(w, x))
    sumwxy = sum(prod, zip(w, x, y))

    y_est = similar(x)
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(y_est)
        wx = w[i] * x[i]
        xxk_0_0 = sumw - w[i]
        xxk_1_0 = sumwx - wx
        xxk_1_1 = sumwxx - wx * x[i]
        xyk_0 = sumwy - w[i] * y[i]
        xyk_1 = sumwxy - wx * y[i]

        det = xxk_0_0 * xxk_1_1 - xxk_1_0 * xxk_1_0
        c0  = (xxk_1_1 * xyk_0 - xxk_1_0 * xyk_1) / det
        c1  = (-xxk_1_0 * xyk_0 + xxk_0_0 * xyk_1) / det

        y_est[i] = c0 + c1 * x[i]
    end
    return y_est
end
```

Comment: Lots of linear algebra operations are going on, it should be multi-threaded, if you haven't set `BLAS.set_num_threads(n)` to 1 or have machine with one logical-core. That's probably what OP meants by "multithreading by default" on MATLAB. BLAS operations are multithreaded by default in Julia as well.

Comment: I don't think any of the above code invokes any BLAS routines. It's all just broadcasted element-wise operations, which do not use BLAS. The exception is my use of `dot` in `w'*x` etc, but I doubt this calls BLAS either. Anyway, changing the number of BLAS threads has no effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is awesome! I can't believe it, now Julia has beaten MATLAB in what it's good at. The next step would be to enable multithreading by default, I mean for normal functions like sum, prod, etc., not just BLAS which is already multithreaded.

Comment: @DNF, You're right. I had seen lots of `*` alone, which belongs to the devectorized version.